# Images referring wrong path

Tags: files, media

I uploaded some images in content. the images are uploaded to "sites/default/files". but in node page the images are referring "sites/default/files/styles/large" path. how to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is showing the image with default image style of the field, you could change it, I will show you with the "Article" Content type,
Goto the page `/admin/structure/types/manage/article/display` you can see the image field in that list, 
just click the gear icon right side of the image field and then change the 'Image Style' as None (Original Image). 
It would show you the original images in the node view page.

Comment: it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

> Images refering wrong path

I would say, Image is not referring any wrong path and there is nothing wrong in what you are seeing. Whatever you are seeing is by design in Drupal.

If you defined the Image style, the corresponding files automatically gets prepared in the folder. Hence if you upload an image the image gets uploaded at one default place which is for `original images`, But if you have defines the image style for that content type, then images gets saved at other place also. Hence In your case both "sites/default/files" and "sites/default/files/styles/large" are true. You can see the same image at two places.

For Example,

I just uploaded the image in Article and article content type has the image style `Large`. So that image gets uploaded at two places, as below in my folder.

```
FOR ORIGINAL IMAGE - sites/default/files/field/image/exampleImage.jpg
FOR LARGE IMAGE STYLE - sites/default/files/styles/large/public/field/image/exampleImage.jpg
```

So, same way, if I declare new Imgae style, like Medium Or Thumbnail, the new file with that name gets created and image gets saved there.

Hence, I am not getting why you want to change the path. There is nothing wrong in path. It is by Drupal's default desing. Hence, you not have any problem in your folders.

**Hence for image, There is not a concept of changing path here. There is a concept of changing the *Image style* and image style choose their own folder automatically which is path.**

So, you can go to Structure/content type/exampleType/Manage Display/ and from there you can change the Image style which you want and that image style will create/choose its own folder automatically.